# "public" and "private" are classes while "protected" isn't?

Tags: ruby

```
irb(main):001:0> public.class
=> Class
irb(main):002:0> private.class
=> Class
```

I'm surprised that the class of `public` is `Class`, the same for `private`, let me continue my test:

```
irb(main):003:0> protected.class
NameError: undefined local variable or method `protected' for main:Object
        from (irb):3
        from D:/Ruby2.0.0/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

Er, now I'm more confused. So my questions are:

1. Are `public` and `private` really classes?
2. Why is `protected` different?

Comment: I am assuming you are not asking what the differences are between `public`, `protected` and `private` but rather why 2 are implemented as classes and the third (`protected`) is implemented differently.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to question 1 is no, [`public`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html#method-i-public) and [`private`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html#method-i-private) are not classes, they are methods on Module, as is [`protected`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Module.html#method-i-protected). They all return `self` though, which in your example is an instance of `Class`.

```
2.1.2 :006 > defined? public
 => "method"
```

As to why `protected` behaves differently, I don’t know. I suspect it has something to do with the top level object (`main`) and how that behaves.

For example, this code:

```
class Foo
  puts public
  puts private
  puts protected
end
```

produces this outut, with no error for `protected`:

```
Foo
Foo
Foo
```

Comment: I suspect there is a special case implemented to not allow protected in the main Object class... after all, that would be synonymous with public, as all object inherit from Object.

Answer (score 0):

As for are they really classes I will differ to someone with more experience than my self.

As for `protected` being different `protected` can be used by any instance of the class or it's subclasses where as `private` can not be called with an explicit receiver. `private` methods can only be called by the class itself or it's direct descendants. `private` methods must be called within the context of the calling object.

This means if I have 2 objects (`obj1` and `obj2`) that are both instances of the same `Class`. `obj1` can call `protected` methods of `obj2` because they are of the same class but `obj1` cannot call `private` methods of `obj2` because those methods are scoped privately to `obj2`.

I am not sure if this answers your question in anyway but I feel that the ability to call these methods from another instance of the same/subclass of the same class has a deep impact on why they are implemented differently.

This is a really great question and I hope someone comes along with a far more in depth explanation as to the true implementation of these.